error handling script failing for declaration
I'm creating a procedure to do error handle my sql scripts, but it's failing for declaration. Not sure what is the problem.
`    
DECLARE
PROCEDURE EXEC (i_statement IN VARCHAR2, i_ignore IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL, i_ignore2 IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL)
    IS
      BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (i_statement);  
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          IF SQLCODE = i_ignore THEN NULL;
        ELSIF SQLCODE = i_ignore2 THEN NULL;
        ELSE
          RAISE;
        END IF;
      END;
    /
    DECLARE
      TYPE tt_table_name IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
      --
      -- List of all tables where column addition is required.
      --
      ct_tab_prpc_data tt_table_name := tt_table_name (
                                          -- List of tables.
                                          'PR_OPERATORS_BKP2',
                                              'PR_OPERATORS_BKP3',
                                          'PR_OPERATORS_BKP4'
                                     );
      --
      v_db_name         VARCHAR2(30);
      v_schema_name     VARCHAR2(30) := USER;
      v_idx             VARCHAR2(30);
    BEGIN
      SELECT UPPER(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'DB_NAME')) INTO v_db_name FROM DUAL;
         v_idx := ct_tab_prpc_data.FIRST;
        WHILE v_idx IS NOT NULL LOOP
            --execute immediate 'Alter table '||ct_tab_prpc_data(v_idx)||' add(CSCLEVEL VARCHAR2(500))';
            EXEC('Alter table ''||ct_tab_prpc_data(v_idx)||'' add(CSCLEVEL VARCHAR2(500))',-01430,-00942);
          v_idx := ct_tab_prpc_data.NEXT(v_idx);
        END LOOP;
END;
    /`


Error report - 
ORA-06550: line 21, column 3: 
PLS-00201: identifier 'EXEC' must be declared 
ORA-06550: line 21, column 3: 
PL/SQL: Statement ignored 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s" 
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error. 
*Action:


It's the "/" and the second DECLARE that are messing it up. A nested subprogram (the exec procedure that is declared in the declaration section of the anonymous pl/sql block) goes after the variable declaration.
DECLARE
    TYPE tt_table_name IS
        TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
      --
      -- List of all tables where column addition is required.
      --
    ct_tab_prpc_data tt_table_name := tt_table_name(
                                          -- List of tables.
                                          'PR_OPERATORS_BKP2',
                                          'PR_OPERATORS_BKP3',
                                          'PR_OPERATORS_BKP4'
                                      );
      --
    v_db_name        VARCHAR2(30);
    v_schema_name    VARCHAR2(30) := user;
    v_idx            VARCHAR2(30);
    PROCEDURE exec (
            i_statement IN VARCHAR2
           ,i_ignore    IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL
           ,i_ignore2   IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL
        ) IS
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( i_statement );
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                IF sqlcode = i_ignore THEN
                    NULL;
                ELSIF sqlcode = i_ignore2 THEN
                    NULL;
                ELSE
                    RAISE;
                END IF;
        END;        
BEGIN
    -- code below is not used anywhere 
    SELECT upper(
        sys_context(
            'USERENV'
           ,'DB_NAME'
        )
    )
      INTO v_db_name
      FROM dual;

    v_idx := ct_tab_prpc_data.first;
    WHILE v_idx IS NOT NULL LOOP
            --execute immediate 'Alter table '||ct_tab_prpc_data(v_idx)||' add(CSCLEVEL VARCHAR2(500))';
        exec(
            'Alter table '||ct_tab_prpc_data(v_idx)||' add(CSCLEVEL VARCHAR2(500))'
           ,-01430
           ,-00942
        );
        v_idx := ct_tab_prpc_data.next(v_idx);
    END LOOP;

END;
/


Note that there were too many quotes in EXEC('Alter table ''||ct_tab_prpc_data(v_idx)||'' add(CSCLEVEL VARCHAR2(500))',-01430,-00942);. Either do not quote the table name or surround it with double quotes.
